# Random Variable probability summation tweaking

Tags: probability, summation, random-variables

[image]

I can't seem to figure out what they do to get to the bottom

Answer (score 3):

You get that by summing a [geometric series](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GeometricSeries.html).